# How to process foreign key when using Multipart in the same controller method?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a dropdown that takes the `destination_name` in the form. In the Place table, I have a foreign key: `destination_id` which has a destination_name against it. In my controller, when I try to set the value of destination_id, I get error 400 saying: `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.`

```
This is entity class: Place.java

package com.tawesomeness.edikshedik.model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Transient;

@Entity
public class Place {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue

    private int place_id;
    private String place_name;
    private String place_tagline;
    private String the_place_itself;
    private String googlemap_code;
    private String things_to_do;
    private String accomodation;
    private String food_and_drink;
    private String how_to_reach;
    private String getting_around;
    private String what_to_buy;
    private String banking_facilities;
    private String internet_facilities;
    private String medical_facilities;
    private String police_station;
    @Transient
    private String encodedImage;
    private int destination_destination_id;
}
```

This is my controller method:

```
@Transactional
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newPlaceAdded", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView newPlaceAdded(
                                      @RequestParam("place_name") String place_name,
                                      @RequestParam("destination_destination_id")int destination_destination_id,
                                      @RequestParam("place_tagline") String place_tagline,
                                      @RequestParam("googlemap_code") String googlemap_code,
                                      @RequestParam("things_to_do") String things_to_do,
                                      @RequestParam("accomodation") String accomodation,
                                      @RequestParam("food_and_drink") String food_and_drink,
                                      @RequestParam("how_to_reach") String how_to_reach,
                                      @RequestParam("getting_around") String getting_around,
                                      @RequestParam("what_to_buy") String what_to_buy,
                                      @RequestParam("banking_facilities") String banking_facilities,
                                      @RequestParam("internet_facilities") String internet_facilities,
                                      @RequestParam("medical_facilities") String medical_facilities,
                                      @RequestParam("police_station") String police_station,
                                      @RequestParam("head_image") MultipartFile head_image,
                                      @ModelAttribute("placeAdded")Place p,
                                      ModelAndView model)
    {
        Place place = new Place();
        try
        {
            place.setPlace_name(place_name);
            place.setDestination_destination_id(destination_destination_id);
            place.setPlace_tagline(place_tagline);
            place.setGooglemap_code(googlemap_code);
            place.setThings_to_do(things_to_do);
            place.setAccomodation(accomodation);
            place.setFood_and_drink(food_and_drink);
            place.setHow_to_reach(how_to_reach);
            place.setGetting_around(getting_around);
            place.setWhat_to_buy(what_to_buy);
            place.setBanking_facilities(banking_facilities);
            place.setInternet_facilities(internet_facilities);
            place.setMedical_facilities(medical_facilities);
            place.setPolice_station(police_station);
            place.setHead_image(head_image.getBytes());
            System.out.println(place.getHead_image());

            model.setViewName("hello");
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            model.addObject("message", "Place not added.");
        }

        System.out.println(place.getDestination_destination_id());
        em.persist(place);
        model.addObject("message", "PlaceAdded");
        return model;
    }
```

This is the part of the view where I've added the dropdown:

```
 <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label col-lg-3" for="destination_destination_id">Select the destination of the place: </label>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                                        <select class="form-control" id="destination_destination_id" name="destination_destination_id" required>
                                            <c:forEach var="destinationList" items="${destinationList}">
                                                <option value="${destinationList.destination_id}">${destinationList.destination_name}
                                                </option>
                                            </c:forEach>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Comment: Okay, once I change the name, id and for fields in the view from destination_destination_id to destination_name, I get the following error 400:


HTTP Status 400 - Required int parameter 'destination_destination_id' is not present

Comment: You are supposed to persist an integer ID, rather than a string. Even if you change the for, name and id field, you have to make changes in the model class, and in the database too. Cause they are looking for and int to get in.

Comment: But isn't it an int too in the model class?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly your problem is not in your code, it's in your **database schema** 
You should consider about knowing database a little more before using for your application. Best of luck.